# Jmeter :Aggregate graph is showing average no of threads on using Merge Results plugin

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Suppose we execute 2000 users in 10 different machines and we merge the results of 10 machines to get the aggregate report. But when we are using the merged .jtl file to create aggregate graph,the No of threads is showing as 200 instead of 2000.
Is there any way so that the aggregate graph[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaTfX.png) will show 2000 no of threads from merged .jtl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pradhan,

I had the same problem and found a solution for that.If you want to see all the 2000 threads do not use same thread group name if the thread group names are same JMeter will not show correct number of threads in the aggregate report , use

```
__machineIP()
```

method to differentiate the threads

Please refer to the  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GquZe.png)

For more information on thread groups you can follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/guide-jmeter-thread-groups/)

[Jmeter machineIp function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP)